# C# Google.ProtocolBuffers -> Generic parse

Tags: c#, generics, protocol-buffers

I receive a byte[]  which represents a message serialized using protocol buffer.

I know the type of the message, it is sent along side the byte[], and i can easily parse it.

```
 MyMessage.ParseFrom(byte[]) .
```

The thing is i do not like repetitive code. Especially when all i wan't this piece of code to transform the byte[] into some derivation of the same type.

So i made a generic parse method :

```
    public static T As<T>(byte[] body)
    {
        var parser = GetParseMethod<T>();
        return (T)parser.Invoke(null, new object[] { body });
    }

     private static MethodInfo GetParseMethod<T>()
    {
        var type = GetType(typeof(T).Name);
        var methods = type.GetMethods(); // 
        var parseFromMethod = methods.Where(m => m.Name == "ParseFrom");
        var parseFromByteArrMethod = parseFromMethod.Single(m => m.GetParameters().Length == 1 && m.GetParameters().First().ParameterType == typeof(byte[]));
        return parseFromByteArrMethod;
    }

     private static Type GetType(string typeName)
    {
        var type = Type.GetType("ReportingApi.Proto." + typeName + ", ReportingApi.Proto", true, true);
        return type;
    }
```

I am unable to find a built in way to parse messages in a generic manner as iv'e implemented above.

**Some additional info for this question .**

1) I generated my code from a "proto2" file to C# 
   using proto-compiler-3.0.0-alpha3

protoc --csharp_out=../ ReportingMessages.proto

2) I am using Google.ProtocolBuffers  2.4.1.555

thanks in advance.

Comment: Considering how protobuf serializes the information into a stream of bytes, I'm not sure how you can do what you want ot do without resorting to creating a proto for a generic envelope that carries the metadata information to help with the generic-coding approach...

Comment: @code4life i didn't understand your reasoning for why this can't be done... Can you allborate ?

Comment: Something like @JonSkeet shows here   https://github.com/google/protobuf/issues/993